# how to print a string contains @ and " in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, string-formatting

For example:I want to write `@"@^@"` by Objective c,but it get error.
Does anyone know how to print a string containing `@`?

Comment: Please, add the code and the error.

Comment: Please elaborate your problem in detail. what actually you want to do and what code you have tried so far?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad thank you,question to be  solved.

Comment: @Nitin thank you,question to be solved

Comment: what `@"@^@"` that? a possible key in a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print `@"@^@"` this like,

```
   NSLog(@"@\"@^@\"");
```

If you want to print `"` then you need to add back slash before it like, `\"`

Hope this will help :)

Comment: You are welcome... :) If it have solved your problem then accept answer as right tick so other people with similar issue can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `\` (BackSlash) to use double quotes in your string.

Example:

```
  NSLog(@"\"@^@\"\"@^@\"");
```

Output :

```
 "@^@""@^@"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with this

```
NSLog(@"\"@\"");
```

The escape character is called backlash.

Comment: Just to clarify, it's called a "backslash", not backlash, which is a very different thing.

Answer (score 0):

It is Special characters. So you can not use directly in your NSLog.
You have to use \ (backSlash) before the " so it will be print it.
Example:-

```
print("\"@")
```

it will print in log "@